# addfield setproperty atk4

Tags: php, css, atk4

I have got a simple but strange problem. I am unable to set size for a single field (anno)
this is my code:

```
$t1 = $tabs->addTab('Esterni');
$f= $t1->add('Form');
$f->setFormClass('horizontal atk-form-horizontal-3col');
$f->addField('line' ,'nome_commerciale','Nome Commerciale');
$f->addField('line','anno','Anno')->setProperty('SIZE',4);
$f->addField('line','esame_petrografico','Esame Petrografico');
if($_GET['more_info']){
    $f->setSource('t_materiali_est');
    $f->setConditionFromGET('id_mat','more_info');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by CSS, which takes precedence over size. You can use style instead:

```
$field->setProperty('style','width: 4em');
```